# How to partition SSD+HDD?

Tags: partitioning, system-installation

I have installed Ubuntu 14.04 on **1TB HDD** and have installed lots of packages and softwares. Now i've bought an **128GB SSD**, I have few questions on how to partition `SSD` and `HDD` and how to move my current installation to `SSD`.

I'm thinking to have `/` and `/home` on **SSD**, and store other files on **HDD**, so how can i partition SSD+HDD to have:

- `/` and `/home` on **SSD**
- have `/home/music`, `/home/videos`, `/home/downloads`, `/home/pictures` on **HDD**
- I have no idea about `swap` partition (should it be on SSD or HDD, actually its empty most of the time now), my laptop has 16 GBs of RAM

I'm planning to have fresh install of `14.04` on **SSD** (and i think i have to), so what is the best way to move currently installed packages to new installation ? i'm planning to use `Aptik` for that, is there a better solution ?

Is `preload` any good and gives performance boost when using **SSD** (i have 16 GBs of RAM)

Comment: Actually i don't know how to mount `/home/Downloads` on HDD, while rest of the `/home is on SSD

Comment: Do you want to create separate partitions for /home/Downloads, /home/music etc.? If so create empty folders with those names under/home and assign those mount points to the Partitions. Ask a new question if you need more details.

Comment: For `/home/music`, I think you mean `$HOME/Music`. Same for `/home/videos`, etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have almost the same setup as me. 128 GB SSD 1.5 TB conventional.

Here is how I would do it:

- Leave everything on the conventional drive for the time being.
- Install and partition the ssd using a live distribution usb stick. I wouldn't even touch your old drive here.
- See if everything boots to the new partition okay. You may need to adjust bios settings to make it boot to your new drive.
- set up the mountpoint

```
sudo -i
mkdir /media/hdd
blkid
```

You will get something like the following:

```
/dev/sda1: UUID="0f6e1051-cf9f-4299-b691-76d0d8c532d1" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda5: UUID="058b6235-7e74-42ce-96c9-59f6cb0a44f3" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/sdb1: UUID="40a50699-a900-4bfe-a9e4-6587c1a83464" TYPE="ext4"
```

copy the UUID of your secondary drive (mine is sdb1)

```
nano /etc/fstab
```

paste in uuid line without the quotes and add some fstab goodness:

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
#                
# / was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=0f6e1051-cf9f-4299-b691-76d0d8c532d1 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=058b6235-7e74-42ce-96c9-59f6cb0a44f3 none            swap    sw              0       0
# /media/hdd on /dev/sdb1
UUID=40a50699-a900-4bfe-a9e4-6587c1a83464 /media/hdd        ext4    defaults    0       2
```

You may need to change the ext4 to something else if your other drive is formatted differently.

Check to make sure mounts properly

```
mount /media/hdd
```

and see if it works.

- make sure permissions are okay in /mnt/hdd/home/username

  ```
  ls -l /mnt/hdd/home/username
  ```

  where username is the name of your user.
  if the permissions look okay skip, if not (still with root)

```
chown username:username -R /media/home/username
```

- Link directories you want in home with those on the ssd

These can be done with user permissions, I would suggest you do this with empty directories: For example Pictures

```
cd ~
rm -rf Pictures
ln -sf /media/hdd/home/username/Pictures .
```

Do this for any directory you expect to take too much space, for me it's Pictures, Music, Documents, Videos

- (optional) Carefully clean up the /media/hdd/ directory with root permissions. By carefully I mean do not delete /media/hdd/home !

Answer (score 1):

I never bothered with preload using an SSD, I don't imagine anything will make Solid State faster than it already is. I think your simplest course of action would be to install 14.04 on your 128 GB SSD mounted at / as you propose and use the 1 TB Hard drive mounted on /home. You don't need swap as you have 16 GB of RAM. I have 8 and never needed it. However, If you wish to Suspend/Hibernate the system you may wish to reserve enough swap space to do so. You will want to copy /home and it's contents to a temporary location and copy it back after your done with the install. If you mount it as is your home will end up at /home/home with predictable results

Comment: you stated "You will want to copy /home and it's contents to a temporary location and copy it back after your done with the install." It's always possible to tell the installer to use the existing /home directory for the new installation's /home, but be sure not to format it. This removes the need to do anything with it after the install.

Comment: @Scooby-2 True, but a mistake could cost you all your data. Not a chance I'm willing to take in advising someone who's skills I don't know.

Comment: Some people would like to "Suspend" the system, which requires swap ...

Comment: @Dor point taken. Edited answer

Comment: @Dor (for future readers): Suspend != Hibernate. Suspend = sleep, Hibernate = sleep to swap