# How do I maintain having two hard drives?

Tags: ssd

Firstly, let me say I am very new to the Linux community. I have only been using Ubuntu for 2 weeks, so I do not know a lot. As well I am not tech savvy so it may be obvious, but I don't see it.

I have a 120 ssd and 1tb hdd, in a rig that was made a few hours ago. I want to make the ssd my boot drive and used frequently files. So how do I set it up so my /home will be on my hdd but specific files/games/boot up will be on ssd.

I have tried looking online but nothing I found fit what I was looking for.

Comment: Did you install in UEFI or BIOS boot mode? Are you dual booting with Windows? If UEFI then make sure all drives are gpt partitioned, but Windows will only boot from gpt partitioned drives with UEFI. If you have a 120GB  you have room for /home on SSD, but then use hard drive for data & backups. I have small backup partition on my SSD for some most critical data on hard drive and larger backup on HDD for /home and configuration files on SSD. I do not consider then only backup. http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: You should be able to choose "Custom" when asked how to partition in the Ubuntu installer. Make "/" on the SSD and "/home" on the HDD. It's self-explanatory, as the installer has an easy-to-use GUI that you should have no problem understanding. Just remember, make a "/" partition on the SSD and a "/home" partition on the HDD.

Answer (score 0):

Hey i would seriously consider LVM if you have the time to research. here are some steps to put your /home on your HDD.

- Create a partition on your HDD - use a partitioning tool like gparted
- Format the HDD with a partitioning tool - use ext4 filesystem
- Mount /home directory to the device - read link below!

Note: you may have to mount /home while using a live cd or you can backup and re-install and choose the "Custom" option during install as mentioned above.

Useful links:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Partitioning/Home/Moving

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mount

Answer (score 0):

If you want specific programs to be on the /home volume, you will need to manually move them there and replace the original files with symbolic links ( see `man ln` ) that point to the other location.  After installing a program you can use `dpkg -L pkgname` to see what files make it up and move them one by one.