# Win 7 on HDD and Ubuntu 14.04 on SSD

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, ssd

new machine, 258G SSD, 500G HDD. Main purpose of the machine is for data analysis, and Ubuntu is my preferred OS. Nonetheless, there are times when I need to use Microsoft Excel, therefore I do need to install Win7.

Right now, I am thinking of the following:

- Ubuntu 14.04 on SSD, but can also access HDD as storage. Only
  selected program and data would be stored on SSD.
- Win 7 on HDD

How should I partition my disks? How can I achieve this plan? Thank you for your help.

Best Regards,

Bai Liping

Comment: Also is system UEFI or BIOS? I do prefer smaller system partitions & larger data partitions. http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd If Windows 7 default install even to UEFI hardware is BIOS. But you can change it to UEFI with some minor changes. But whichever way you install Windows, is the way you should install Ubuntu.

Comment: There are so many possible ways to do this that your question really can't be answered. A Google search *restricted to this site* returned [39,100 hits.](https://www.google.com/search?client=ubuntu&channel=fs&q=how+to+partition+site%3Aaskubuntu.com&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8) Also, [WINE can run Excel pretty well,](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=application&iId=11) so you might want to consider using that if your only reason for keeping Windows around is to run Excel. Running Windows in VirtualBox is another option.

Comment: Rod Smith, thank you for your suggestion. I'll consider using VirtualBox for Excel. That is very good information. Thank you.;

Answer (score 0):

This is something very simple to set up.  I would utilize the boot menu of the motherboard to get things working.  If you already have one OS set up, just disconnect the hard drive you don't want to overwrite.

Once everything is set with Linux on the SSD and Windows on the HDD, you can add the mount point for the HDD editing /etc/fstab.  You will need to get the uuid of the drive you want to mount though.

Create a mount point in /mnt/ like Windows, or whatever you want to call it.  With the uuid of the drive, mount the ntfs partion at that mount point.

Once you have got it configured, you can add the windows boot link to your grub menu by using sudo update-grub.  On the next boot you should see the Windows 7 boot loader.