# How to migrate and setup Ubuntu 14.04 installation to SSD?

Tags: partitioning, hard-drive, ssd

First, there is a lot of similar question everywhere, even here on AskUbuntu. I have bought Samsung 850 Evo Basic, 120 GB model. I have existent system installed on classic 500GB HDD. Question is, how to migrate existent Ubuntu installation from HDD to SSD, and tweak SSD for optimal performance using Ubuntu 14.04. I have 8GB of RAM, should I disable swap and how frequently should I run trim? Setting cron job seem like good idea.

Disk usage is as follows:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda7       131G   32G   92G  26% /
none            4,0K     0  4,0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3,9G  4,0K  3,9G   1% /dev
tmpfs           797M  1,4M  796M   1% /run
none            5,0M     0  5,0M   0% /run/lock
none            3,9G   84K  3,9G   1% /run/shm
```

none            100M   28K  100M   1% /run/user

Can I just cp all from / and then update GRUB?

Comment: I believe in clean installs. Or just install to SSD. You can export a list of installed applications to reinstall & copy  most or all of /home to SSD either as separate partition, or inside / (root) to have all your configurations & data. Then make HDD as data partition(s) for most of your data. One of many threads with alternative suggestions on partitioning: http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd

Comment: @user68186, see edit, df -h output.

Answer (score 1):

Download the latest stable Clonezilla version (iso) :

http://sourceforge.net/projects/clonezilla/files/clonezilla_live_stable/

Create a bootable media (CD/USB) from the iso file.

Boot from this former created Clonezilla live media.

Create a backup from your HDD ubuntu partition(s).

Restore the backup to your SSD.

Boot from ubuntu install media.

Reinstall the GRUB bootloader.

You as well can clone and restore the whole disk (depending on your environment).

In case you do partition restore, do not forget to update /etc/fstab file afterwards.

SAMSUNG SSDs are well supported by ubuntu including automatic trim operations.

For further maintenance and servicing you can use SAMSUNG SSD Magician DC ->

http://www.samsung.com/global/business/semiconductor/minisite/SSD/global/html/support/server_downloads.html/

Disabling swap is not a good idea - for performance reason create a swap partition.

You can do that by using GParted which is already available in ubuntu install media.

Comment: Should I boot the Clonezilla image or how can I make a backup? You should explain that in your answer.

Comment: Swap of 8gb is unnecessary for 2 reasons : OP has 8gb ram and it decreases ssd life. And also eats up space which could be used for something else. Keeping 512mb swap file is good enough, not 8gb partition

Comment: @Serg - there are different opinions on this topic - anyway I updated my answer, so now it's up to the user to decide - thanks for contribution.

Comment: Simple and neat. Are there any further tweaks for Ubuntu on SSD? Should I put /home on HDD? Or leave all on SSD, my / is under 40GB, and swap is 8GB.

Comment: There is nothing serious you should care about. I have a 250 GB SAMSUNG 840 EVO in use for 7 months now and /home on the SSD within ubuntu. Anyway I save my data on a separate partition on the second built-in HDD. I do regular checks with SAMSUNG Magician DC, there are less than 10 GB per day written, which means an approximately lifetime span for more than 10 years and your (newer) 850 EVO SSD has even much more. Again - ubuntu supports SAMSUNG SSDs very well ! By the way, as it seems you have appreciated my answer, would you mind accepting / upvoting it ?