# Trying to do a dual boot install of Ubuntu. How do I get Windows to stop booting?

Tags: dual-boot

I have 1 TB HHD and 250 GB SSD. I installed Windows 10 on the HDD with 100 GB for Steam on the SSD. I am trying to install Ubuntu but Windows keeps loading. I installed Windows in UEFI mode. I changed the boot preferences so the HDD and Windows are last in order. Occasionally I get a flash of the Install Ubuntu screen but it bypasses and just loads Windows.

Also do you think I should install Ubuntu on the SSD and use the HDD for data storage or just do it the same as I installed Windows?

Comment: Did you try re-configuring bootmgr by `bcdedit /set {bootmgr} path \EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi`?

Comment: I ended up using the Windows repair screen and there was an option for my usb linpus lite but I've decided to do a full reinstall of windows anyway. How would I go about doing that anyway?

Comment: UEFI or BIOS? If UEFI, you must use gpt partitioning with Windows. Best just to install Windows as with UEFI it wants lots of partitions. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DiskSpace & http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu & http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd