# installation of Ubuntu 20.04 on SSD+HDD

Tags: system-installation, hard-drive, ssd, 20.04

Can anyone guide me to install **ubuntu 20.04** in a laptop with **both SSD and HDD**. I have 240gb SSD and a 1TB HDD in my laptop. What is the best partition config to install ?
How much space should the `/root` be given? Is `/home` necessary separately and whether it be on the HDD or SSD?
The laptop runs on Intel(R) Core(TM) i5-5200U CPU @ 2.20GHz with 12 Gigs of RAM

Comment: There must be many of the same question here. Are you dual booting? Should be UEFI with that CPU. I normally suggest 25 or 30GB for (root),if you have separate /home or separate data partition(s).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI Ubuntu now uses swap file, so swap partition not required. One older similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/461394/how-to-partition-ssdhdd Be sure to use gpt. http://askubuntu.com/questions/743095/how-to-prepare-a-disk-on-an-efi-based-pc-for-ubuntu &
https://askubuntu.com/questions/343268/how-to-use-manual-partitioning-during-installation

Comment: Its UEFI and I want a fresh install. Would I have to do all the stuff like creating a mount point using live usb? Wouldn't the Ubuntu installation just take care of that?

Comment: The live installer has multiple options, some totally erase drive. So if not booting anything else you can use those. If dual booting with Windows you have to make sure Windows NTFS is seen in installer or it may erase it. That can be because Windows fast start up is on, or UEFI needs update or SSD firmware needs update. I prefer Something Else, as then you see partitions and choose yourself. But do have to have some understanding of partitions. Auto install usually works, but may not do exactly what you want.